# In a graph db, is there a limit on how many node labels you can have?

Tags: neo4j, amazon-neptune, graphdb, dgraph

I'm considering making hundreds of thousands of nodes with their own labels and connecting them to each other via millions of edges.

Has this sort of thing been benchmarked anywhere with Neo4j, Dgraph, or any other graph db?

Comment: Labels in a graph database are meant to group vertices and edges of similar types together (e.g. Person, Company, Movie).  Having hundreds of thousands of different ones seems like you are really looking to use a property instead of a label.  Can you give some context as to why you need this many labels?

Comment: I was thinking about making a plugin API where people could create generic nodes. Whatever they named the node would be its label. They could make connections to other plugins via edges.

Comment: In this use case I would probably make that "name" assigned to a node a property and just use a generic label for the node type.  If each node is going to have a different label than the grouping aspect of a label is no longer relevant so allowing faceted search on a property (with the appropriate index) would be a better model

Comment: Good idea! Thank you so much @bechbd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 4 billions in Neo4j, reference here : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/store-info/#neo4j-admin-store-format-versions